# Why do my failed jobs disappear after migration to Laravel 5.8?

Tags: laravel, laravel-queue, laravel-5.8

I have a Laravel project with a queue, running ~1000 jobs a day.

When a job is failing, in 5.7, it was moved to failed_jobs table, and I was able to retry it.

After migration to Laravel 5.8, jobs just disappear.

This code should mark a job as failed and put it in the failed-jobs table.

```php
    /**
     * Execute the job.
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        throw new \Exception('WRONG JOB');
    }
```

Supervisor log in that case:

```
[2019-04-10 15:07:57][11932] Processing: App\Jobs\ExecuteAction
```

It seems that execution stops, and Queue::failing event is not called.

This code works, but doesn't seem right to me.

```php
class ExecuteAction implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        try {
            throw new \Exception('WROOONG');
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            if ($this->attempts() < $this->tries) {
                $this->release(10);
            } else {
                $this->fail($e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Queue::failing event is called.

Supervisor log ;

```
[2019-04-10 15:06:52][11926] Processing: App\Jobs\ExecuteAction
[2019-04-10 15:06:52][11926] Failed:     App\Jobs\ExecuteAction
[2019-04-10 15:06:52][11926] Processed:  App\Jobs\ExecuteAction
```

In supervisor conf

```
command=php /path/to/laravel-project/artisan queue:listen
```

What I am doing wrong ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What queue driver are you using?

Comment: Hi, I'm using `database`.

Comment: If you do not specify the --tries option. The job will never be stored in the failed table...

Comment: @shock_gone_wild It's not obvious after reading the documentation, but by looking into Worker code in framework, it seems you're right.  The doc also explains that I can use `public $tries = 5;` in my Job Class, but it's seems it's not used.

Comment: As far as I can tell is, that public $tries  = 5 is working. I just tested it with specifying --tries=2 and without specifying --tries ind the worker command. In both cases after 5 attempts the job is sent to the failed jobs table

Answer (score 1):

**From:** https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues

The command: `queue:listen` was removed from the documentation and now the recommended way to work with queues is to run: `queue:work`.

**See:** https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#running-the-queue-worker

**Or you may use:** [Laravel Horizon](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/horizon)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. I use `queue:listen` because of a memory leak after a few thousands of jobs on http requests. I've tried `queue:work` and the problem is the same. About Horizon, I cannot use it as my queue connection is `database` and it's only work with `redis`.

Comment: Do you can provide the log?